# QGIS 2.18.13 Points at intersections have More Information with the ID than what is in the database fields?

Tags: query, database

Created Point Feature Class at all street intersections. When looking at the database fields I only get two fields yet when i use the Info tool I get several paragraphs of information including the intersecting street names which I really need. Where is this extra information stored?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is stored in your attribute table but you might be looking at the wrong layer. You can find this data by right clicking the layer in the layers panel and selecting open attribute table.

If you are still lost, can you screenshot your qgis window? Specifically, just need to see the layers panel and the identify results panel.